# Datastax connection exception when using beeline or hive2 jdbc driver (Tableau)

Tags: cassandra, tableau-api, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I have installed `Datastax` enterprise 2.8 on my dev VM (Centos 7). The install went through smoothly and the single node cluster is working great. But when I try to connect to the cluster using beeline or hive2 jdbc driver I get an error as shown below. My main aim is to connect Tableau using the Datastax Enterprise driver or Spark Sql driver.

Error observed is:

> ERROR 2016-04-14 17:57:56,915
>   org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during
>   processing of message. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status -128
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
>   ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
>           at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:269)
>   ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [na:1.7.0_99]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [na:1.7.0_99]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_99] Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status
>   -128
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
>   ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:184)
>   ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125)
>   ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271)
>   ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
>   ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
>   ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
>           ... 4 common frames omitted ERROR 2016-04-14 17:58:59,140 org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend:
>   Application has been killed. Reason: Master removed our application:
>   KILLED
>
> My cassandra.yml config:
>
> cluster_name: 'Cluster1'
>
> num_tokens: 256
>
> hinted_handoff_enabled: true hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
>   max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
>
> batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
>
> authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
>
> authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
>
> permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
>
> partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
>
> data_file_directories:
>        - /var/lib/cassandra/data
>
> commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
>
> disk_failure_policy: stop
>
> commit_failure_policy: stop
>
> key_cache_size_in_mb:
>
> key_cache_save_period: 14400
>
> row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
>
> row_cache_save_period: 0
>
> counter_cache_size_in_mb:
>
> counter_cache_save_period: 7200
>
> saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
>
> commitlog_sync: periodic commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
>
> commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
>
> seed_provider:
>       - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
>         parameters:
>             - seeds: "10.33.1.124"
>
> concurrent_reads: 32 concurrent_writes: 32 concurrent_counter_writes:
>   32
>
> memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
>
> index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
>
> index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
>
> trickle_fsync: false trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
>
> storage_port: 7000
>
> ssl_storage_port: 7001
>
> listen_address: 10.33.1.124
>
> start_native_transport: true native_transport_port: 9042
>
> start_rpc: true
>
> rpc_address: 10.33.1.124
>
> rpc_port: 9160
>
> rpc_keepalive: true
>
> rpc_server_type: sync
>
> thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
>
> incremental_backups: false
>
> snapshot_before_compaction: false
>
> auto_snapshot: true
>
> tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000 tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
>
> column_index_size_in_kb: 64
>
> batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 64
>
> compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
>
> compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
>
> sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
>
> read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000 range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
>   write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000 counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms:
>   5000 cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
>   truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000 request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
>
> cross_node_timeout: false
>
> endpoint_snitch: com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch
>
> dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
>   dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
>   dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
>
> request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
>
> server_encryption_options:
>       internode_encryption: none
>       keystore: resources/dse/conf/.keystore
>       keystore_password: cassandra
>       truststore: resources/dse/conf/.truststore
>       truststore_password: cassandra
>
> client_encryption_options:
>       enabled: false
>       optional: false
>       keystore: resources/dse/conf/.keystore
>       keystore_password: cassandra
>
> internode_compression: dc
>
> inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
>
> concurrent_counter_writes: 32
>
> counter_cache_size_in_mb:
>
> counter_cache_save_period: 7200
>
> memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
>
> index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
>
> index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
>
> sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
>
> counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
>
> When connecting with beeline, I get the error:
>
> dse beeline Beeline version 0.12.0.11 by Apache Hive beeline> !connect
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000 scan complete in 10ms Connecting to
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000 Enter username for
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000: cassandra Enter password for
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000: ********* Error: Invalid URL:
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000 (state=08S01,code=0) 0:
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000> !connect
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000 Connecting to
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000 Enter username for
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000:  Enter password for
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000:  Error: Invalid URL:
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000 (state=08S01,code=0) 1:
>   jdbc:hive2://10.33.1.124:10000>

I see similar errors when connecting through `Tableau` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDBC driver connects to the SparkSql Thrift server. If you do not start it, you cannot connect to it.

```
dse spark-sql-thriftserver
/Users/russellspitzer/dse/bin/dse:
usage: dse spark-sql-thriftserver <command> [Spark SQL Thriftserver Options]

Available commands:
  start                             Start Spark SQL Thriftserver
  stop                              Stops Spark SQL Thriftserver
```